# Obtaining a message content from signed message

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, digital-signature

Initially I need to encrypt a certain message using my encryption implementation, then sign the message with an signature using RSA and send it all to a certain class where the signature should be verified and the message itself decrypted. The problem is that I don't understand how to retrieve the message itself from the signed message.

```
public class Voter {

private KeyPairGenerator generator;
private KeyPair pair;

...

public Voter(String firstName, String lastName, String sex, String age) throws Exception {
    ...

    generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
    generator.initialize(2048, new SecureRandom());
    pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
}

public String createBallot (String candidateName, String candidateSurname) {
    return "Candidate: " + candidateSurname + " " + candidateSurname +
            "; Voter: " + this.lastName + " " + this.firstName;
}


public void vote(String ballot, String gammaKey) {
    String encryptedBallot = encrypt(ballot, gammaKey);
    byte[] signedMessage = signMessage(encryptedBallot);
    votingSystem.addBallot(signedMessage);
}

private byte[] signMessage(String message) throws Exception {
    Signature privateSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    privateSignature.initSign(pair.getPrivate());
    privateSignature.update(message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    return privateSignature.sign();
}

private String encrypt(String message, String gammaKey) {
    gammaKey = fitGammaToMessage(message.length(), gammaKey);
    StringBuilder encyptedMessage = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++) {
        char C = (char) (message.charAt(i) ^ gammaKey.charAt(i));
        encyptedMessage.append(C);
    }

    return encyptedMessage.toString();
}


public class VotingSystem {

...

private ArrayList<byte[]> ballots = new ArrayList<>();




...

public void addBallot(byte[] ballot) {
    ballots.add(ballot);
}

private boolean verifySign(byte[] ballot, PublicKey publicKey) throws Exception {
    Signature publicSignature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    publicSignature.initVerify(publicKey);
    publicSignature.update(??? How do I get the message itself???message.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    return publicSignature.verify(ballot);
}}
```

Comment: Or probably I should pass the message and the signature separately because they are the things that are absolutely not related to each other?

Comment: I think this is a misunderstanding. your `signMessage` function does not return a signed message but a signature. A signature applies a hash function on the message and then generates a signature of the hash. Hash functions are one-way trap door functions, which means they can not be reversed, so getting a message from it's signature is impossible. You have to save the message and the signature and transmit both.